# Override Page.php to change loader-2.gif

Tags: magento2, image, backend

In Page.php, the loaderIcon is assigned to loader-2.gif. I'd like to reassign this image to my image. However, that involves changing this file.

Is there an easy way to either override this attribute specifically, or maybe override the function in question, or even override the entire file?

The function from Page.php:

```
// 'magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php'

/**
 * @param ResponseInterface $response
 * @return $this
 */
protected function render(ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $this->pageConfig->publicBuild();
    if ($this->getPageLayout()) {
        $config = $this->getConfig();
        $this->addDefaultBodyClasses();
        $addBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head.additional'); // todo
        $requireJs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('require.js');
        $this->assign([
            'requireJs' => $requireJs ? $requireJs->toHtml() : null,
            'headContent' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderHeadContent(),
            'headAdditional' => $addBlock ? $addBlock->toHtml() : null,
            'htmlAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_HTML),
            'headAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_HEAD),
            'bodyAttributes' => $this->pageConfigRenderer->renderElementAttributes($config::ELEMENT_TYPE_BODY),
            'loaderIcon' => $this->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-2.gif'),
        ]);

        $output = $this->getLayout()->getOutput();
        $this->assign('layoutContent', $output);
        $output = $this->renderPage();
        $this->translateInline->processResponseBody($output);
        $response->appendBody($output);
    } else {
        parent::render($response);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I'd like to make the following change:

```
'loaderIcon' => $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icons/loading.svg'),
```

We're also considering a url rewrite or generating an animated gif out of our svg, in the worst case.

Thanks in advance!

Best
Michael

Comment: Anyone? *crickets*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I arrived at was to override the loader-2.gif using CSS, e.g.

```
> .loading-mask {
    .loader {
        $loader-size: 40px;

        img {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: $loader-size;
            height: $loader-size;
            padding-left: $loader-size;
            background-image: url('#{$baseDir}images/icons/loading.svg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just override these files in your custom theme

- web/css/source/lib/variables/_loaders.less
- web/images/loader-1.gif
- web/images/loader-2.gif

to get the desired result. By this way you can replace all spinners.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to replace the gif with an svg, so I can't properly override the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative solution by overriding the following file in my own theme folder : `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml`

Change the `$loaderIcon` variable to `$this->getViewFileUrl('loader-path.svg')`.